# DSA - Signing a message in Python to verify in C#

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x, cryptography

Good day,
I'm generating a message on C# that has to be passed to a RPC server in python 3.7 which will sign it and give it back to C# to verify.

I just recently started to learn cryptography and python and whatever I sign can't then be verified in C#, I followed every doc I could find and I think I'm using the same algorithms.

This is how I generate the keys, since the .Net library generates xml keys I then convert the private one to .pem with BouncyCastle utilities to work with python's pycryptodome library:

```
using (DSA dsa = new DSACng(2048))
{
   var privateKey = dsa.ToXmlString(true);
   var publicKey = dsa.ToXmlString(false);
   File.WriteAllText("privateKey.xml", privateKey);
   File.WriteAllText("publicKey.xml", publicKey);

   AsymmetricCipherKeyPair dsaKey = DotNetUtilities.GetDsaKeyPair(dsa);
   using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("privateKey.pem"))
   {
      PemWriter pw = new PemWriter(sw);
      pw.WriteObject(dsaKey);
   }
}
```

Then in python:

```
def sign_message(par1, par2, par3):
   message = _generate_message(par1, par2, par3).encode('utf-8')
   h = SHA256.new(message)
   b64Message = base64.b64encode(h.digest())
   f = open("privateKey.pem", "r")
   key = DSA.import_key(f.read())
   signer = DSS.new(key, 'fips-186-3')
   signature = signer.sign(h)
   b64Signature = base64.b64encode(signature)

   return [b64Message, b64Signature]
```

But then if I verify the message in C# it only prints out "Not verified":

```
using(DSA dsa = new DSACng(2048)
{
   byte[] message = response[0];
   byte[] signature = response[1];
   var publicKey =  File.ReadAllText("publicKey.xml");
   dsa.FromXmlString(publicKey);
   if (dsa.VerifyData(message, signature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256))
       Console.WriteLine("Verified");
   else
       Console.WriteLine("Not verified");
}
```

What is wrong in my code? Any help is appreciated

Comment: I don't see you decode the message and signature in C#, that's missing from your code. Note that you should not generate the private key on the verification side if you want to be secure.

Comment: I saw no point in trying to decode the message if the verification didn't work in first place. The key generation part is a one-time only, I generate the key and I delete that part before deploying (I only need that one key, no need to generate more).

Comment: OK, but you base 64 encode the signature, and the decoding of that is missing in the C# code, right?